# Pass data in components

Tags: reactjs, components, state

Hello i am having components:

DropDownList with state:

```
 this.state = {
    selectValue: 1
};
```

Tab components with state:

```
 this.state = {
   selectValueInDropDown: 1
};
```

Tabs and DropDownList together in one component Page.

How can i pass the state `selectValue` from `DropDownList` to the `Tab` component via component `Page`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "lift" the state up to a parent component that will hold the data in its state and pass the data as `props` to the child components.

In this example we have

1. A parent component `<App/>` - that holds the `state`
2. A child component `<Select />` that accepts props such as
   The `options` to display the drop-down options list The `onChange`
   event to notify about changing an option and passing the event
   upwards The `selected` props to determine which option is selected
3. A `<Tab/>` component that only displays the selected option

The `App` will manage the state for both children as they have a  portion of the state in common (the selected `option`).

Code:

```js
const Select = ({ selected, options, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <select onChange={onChange}>
      {options.map(o => (
        <option value={o} selected={o == selected}>
          {o}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

const Tab = ({ selected }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>The selected value is: {selected}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: "",
      optionList: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    };

    this.onOptionChange = this.onOptionChange.bind(this);
  }

  onOptionChange(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedOption, optionList } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Tab selected={selectedOption} />
        <Select
          onChange={this.onOptionChange}
          selected={selectedOption}
          options={optionList}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```